# How to access System properies in karaf features file

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I added a feature in karaf features xml

```
<feature name="dummy-feature" version="1.1.1">
<bundle>file:${MY_VARIABLE}/temp.jar</bundle>
</feature>
```

MY_VARIABLE is the system property that has the directory path.

But when i try to install the feature i am getting error.

```
Invalid syntax for instruction [{MY_VARIABLE}/temp.jar]. Take a look at http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd.
```

In the karaf console when i enter ${MY_VARIABLE} i see the value that i have set.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. Sometimes you will see placeholders in the source of feature files but these are replaced by maven at build time.

So the way to make your paths system independent is to use mvn urls cand set a custom maven repo in the pax url config.